# Nginx rewrite to remove .php from files has no effect but to redirect to homepage

Tags: nginx, php, rewrite, redirect, regex

I'm trying to make a rewrite to remove .php from my URLs but so far no luck. Here's what I've got so far and then my results with this config below.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri/ @extensionless-php;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass hhvm;
  fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
  fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
  fastcgi_cache ASPS;
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php last;
}
```

**This leads to:**

example.com/page1.php going to example.com/page1.php and rendering properly
example.com/page1 rendering the index.php
example.com/page1/ rendering the index.php

Has anyone run into this? This seems like a very common thing to do but I'm having hours and hours of trouble with it and have searched endlessly online.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `location ~ \.php$` block does not see URIs like `example.com/page1` as they do not match the regex.

You should place your `try_files $uri/ @extensionless-php;` directive into a different location - usually `location /` (which will see all URIs *except* those ending in `.php`).

Try something like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    if ($request_uri ~ (.*)\.php$) { 
        return 301 $1; 
    }

    try_files $uri =404;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass hhvm;
    fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
    fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
    fastcgi_cache ASPS;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```

EDIT: In order to remove the extension from URLs ending in `.php`, the `location ~ \.php$` block needs to distinguish externally presented URLs from the internal rewrite. One way to achieve this is to test `$request_uri` with a `if` block. Use with caution, as externally rewriting `.php` URLs will likely break some applications, particularly when POSTing forms.

Comment: Wow thanks that's a big help. If I could ask a followup, is there something else that needs to be done to get .php URLs to redirect to these new extensionless ones?

Comment: @Slapbox I have updated the answer - but note the caution.

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks so much. I definitely see the problem with posting forms now. I only have two forms. Is there a way I can manually exclude them?
    

Sorry I'm pretty helpless when it comes to Regex and Nginx despite my best attempts. I just don't use either enough to get very familiar.
    

I marked your reply as the answer and thanks again for your help and for any additional tips you can give me!

Comment: Haha! I got it! Thank you so much dude. You really saved me from driving myself mad. It's been hours I've been at this.